# Matrix Addition

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, addition

So I have to make a matrix calculator for my ap class, but when I go to add the matrix together it doesn't add correctly, it only adds the first number of each array. Please Help

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MatricAddition {



public static void main(String[] args) {
   Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.print("Enter number of rows: ");
   int rows = s.nextInt();
   System.out.print("Enter number of columns: ");
   int columns = s.nextInt();
   int[][] a = new int[rows][columns];
   int[][] b = new int[rows][columns];
   System.out.println("Enter the first matrix");
   for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
       for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
           a[i][j] = s.nextInt();
       }
   }
   System.out.println("Enter the second matrix");
   for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
       for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
           b[i][j] = s.nextInt();
       }
   }
   int[][] c = new int[rows][columns];
   for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
       for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
           c[i][j] = a[i][j] + b[i][j];
       }
   }
   System.out.println("The sum of the two matrices is");
   for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
       for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
           System.out.print(c[i][j] + " ");
       }
       System.out.println();
   }
  }
 }
```

Thanks for the help in advance.
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbzdu.png)

Comment: I think its working fine.

Comment: I think it is correct.

Comment: @Noah provide your input and output. But this code is right.

Comment: Can you provide an example with input with expected output and the actual output ?

Comment: I copied your code; ran it; entered "1 2 3 4" two times, and I get "2 4 6 8" as result. All fine. Whatever your problem is; it is **not** in the code you are sharing with us.

Comment: the Code is wrKing Fine..!!    Enter number of rows: 3
Enter number of columns: 3
Enter the first matrix
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
Enter the second matrix
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
The sum of the two matrices is
2 4 6 
8 10 12 
14 16 18

Comment: I uploaded the output

Comment: maybe input wants "," between them but you press enter after each, not after all? so it adds only 1+1

Comment: Well, I feel like a complete idiot now. Thanks everyone for the help.